# Batch inserts in a Postgresql table from an external file using hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate, batch-file, jdbc, hql

I have an external file containing multiple records.(around 60k).Now I want to insert them in a postgresql table.I have the hbm.xml and hibernate.cfg mapped to my database.I have the getter-setter methods written for the class as well.

I went to the hibernate documentation about batch inserts but could not figure out how to process my file and add it to the hibernate code.
Please see the below sample code snippet:

```
public void addEmployees( ){
      Session session = factory.openSession();
      Transaction tx = null;
      Integer employeeID = null;
      try{
         tx = session.beginTransaction();
         for ( int i=0; i<100000; i++ ) {
            String fname = ...
            String lname = ...
            Integer salary = ..;
            Employee employee = new Employee(fname, lname, salary);
            session.save(employee);
            if( i % 50 == 0 ) {
               session.flush();
               session.clear();
            }
         }
     tx.commit();
```

The file structure is as below:

```
abc xyz 450
cde qwe 908
qwe fgh 1009
```

In the above code,the fname,lname an salary are to be input from the file.Please let me know a way to insert them from the file.An obvious way is to parse the file , but I am not sure if this is the way to do it.

Comment: I can't see how to avoid parsing the file

Comment: The thing is I have a file that has around 60k records with around 15 columns.Is there any way other than that ?

Comment: Why do you want to use Hibernate? If the data in the file matches the table structure in the database, you can load it directly, using [`COPY`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.2/static/sql-copy.html).

Comment: If the file is local to your server, use `COPY`. Else use [`\copy` in psql](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/app-psql.html).

Comment: @TomAnderson Even if it doesn't match - you can still load it with `COPY` to a temporary table and `INSERT ... SELECT ...` them to destination table.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko: True. I was thinking that if the structure doesn't match, then the transformation needed may embody business logic, in which case it is better to use the code already written on top of Hibernate which does this. But if the transformation is trivial, then yes, that would be a good idea.